# Add random number to .css so it doesn't cache

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the styles.css to not cache as the server is having issues with the css when it caches.

```
<script>
var numBAH = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
</script>

<link href="styles.css+ numBAH +" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Technically, `(+new Date())` would be better than `Math.random()` as the random number could theoretically repeat.

Comment: What do you mean, "the server is having issues"? The whole point of caching is so that you DON'T hit the server.

Comment: I don't think my code is actually functional so I was hoping someone could rewrite this.

Comment: The **server** has issues with the CSS?  What does that mean?

Comment: It looks like you meant to put the random number in the query string, and in your example the requested file's name is `"styles.css  numBAH  "`.

Comment: So it takes a few seconds for the css to load the first time which is good because of some dynamic content on a page, but after is cashes it loads too quickly rendering the page wrong in the clients eyes.

Comment: "it loads too quickly" ? That's a novel problem. I think you should try to define explicitly a transition because you can't be sure of the network speed. Really I think making the css slower to fetch is a wrong solution.

Comment: "after it caches it loads too quickly rendering the page wrong in the clients eyes", sounds like something else might be happening here. What exactly is the problem the client is seeing when it "loads too fast"?

Comment: It loads too fast from the cached version.  It's just strange I know it's not ideal and major hack, but thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have access to a server-side language it would be neater to render the link tag with a query string that is a hash of the entire content of the file. In that way, the cache invalidator ey will change only when the content of the file has actually changed.

---

After having seen the discussion that has followed, about how you *never* want to use cache, because it *loads too quickly*, I want to change my answer. Not to `new Date()`, but to: fix your page so that loading quickly is a desired result. If you're having specific problems with that, create a question that targets those problems, don't go directly for the lousy workaround.

Comment: Ideally if you did this you'd want to calculate the hash at build/deploy time, not when the request is being served. Not clear from your answer but it sounds like you might be saying to compute the hash at the time the page is served. If you do that it would be good to have a strategy of caching the computed hash so you don't have to scan the file every time a page needs link that .css file.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this in the head of your document :

```
<script>
document.write('<link href="styles.css?r='+ Math.floor(Math.random()*100) +'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
</script>
```

BUT :

- you have great probabilities of finding two times the same number
- you shouldn't generally avoid caching

Solutions I propose :

1) use `(new Date()).getTime()` instead of a random number

2) simply change the number when the version changes : `styles.css?v=3` (without javascript)

Comment: You could also use `(new Date()).getTime()` to generate the unique number for cache busting purposes.

Comment: Is there away to do it without document.write because the styles load slow when I do that.

Comment: @chinabuffet You commented while I was adding the 2 solutions :\

Comment: @Blynn using `document.write()` will not affect the speed with which the files load.  Of course the main problem is that you're forcing the CSS to load in the first place - it's much better to let the file be cached with a workably short expiration time to allow for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Cache busting can be work without server-side rendering.
I tested recent versions of firefox, chrome and safari in both mobile and desktop, this code worked. (I'm Not sure about IE, though..)

```
<HEAD>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    var numBAH = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);

    document.write('<LI' + 'NK HREF="./path/to/style.css?cacheBusting='+numBAH+'" rel="stylesheet">');
    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
```

Comment: Why are you breaking the "LI+NK"?